# parsing inconsistency of date -d

Tags: linux, date

How is the `date` parser working?

```
date -d "2010-08-12 05:30:30.102 AM + 0 months"
Thu Aug 12 05:30:30 EDT 2010
```

but

```
date -d "2010-08-12 05:30:30.102 + 0 months"
Thu Aug 12 01:30:30 EDT 2010
```

Comment: This is strange, for both, I get `Thu Aug 12 05:30:30 CDT 2010` and `Sun Sep 12 00:30:30 CDT 2010` -- I got nothing for you there... `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release`

Comment: Here's my guess... In one case, it may think the `+` is for the timezone UTC offset. When you add `AM` an ambiguity is resolved and it is parsed appropriately. Perhaps because time offsets are only part of the spec when 24-hour time is used. The result, however, is always displayed in local time.

Comment: @sytech, good guess. If I `date -d "2010-08-12 05:30:30 EDT + 0 months"`, I get results similar to those with `AM` included, and `date -d "2010-08-12 05:30:30 + 2 months"` produces **Sep 11 23:30:30 EDT**. So the `+0` is indeed being interpreted as a timezone offset, and the `months` is being interpreted as "+ 1 month". Post an answer! You called it!

Comment: I don't know how the poster avoids the `+ 1 months` interpretation. That must be a LOCALE issue. Agree @sytech, write it up. you scurried down the correct rabbit-hole first.

Comment: Well, ambiguous inputs will get you ambiguous outputs. When in doubt, one  should refer to `ISO-8601` for the date format. Otherwise, you're at the mercy of someone who made a decision on how to parse what you provided.

Comment: True story. Just checked: `date -u -d "2010-08-12 05:30:30.102 AM + 0 seconds" "+%s"` is ***`1281591030`*** and `date -u -d "2010-08-12 05:30:30.102 + 0 seconds" "+%s"` is ***`1281591031`***.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `date -d "2010-08-12 05:30:30 AM +0"` would be considered invalid (the command fails). Supporting the assertion that UTC offsets are only possible when 24-hour time is used (or assumed).

Comment: Also worth noting that the word "months" gets interpreted as either "0 months" or "1 month" depending on either your version of GNU date or your LOCALE (it's unclear). With `date` from coreutils 7.4 (Ubuntu 10.04), I get a date in September (as did David), whereas the other comments here seem to show dates in August.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be the case that the `+ 0` is being interpreted as a UTC offset when `AM` is not included. However, when `AM` is included, it's no longer ambiguous whether or not the `+ 0` is for the offset or if it's belonging to `months` because UTC offsets are only valid when 24-hour time is used.

In the former case, `months` alone is being interpreted as `+ 1 months` (at least in some versions of `date`) as ghoti mentioned in the comments.

Also consider that `date -d "2010-08-12 05:30:30 +0"` is an acceptable format. However `date -d "2010-08-12 05:30:30 AM +0"` is invalid because UTC offsets can't be used when `AM` is present.

Comment: One strategy might be to provide a timezone offset. The following assumes a local timezone, with offset adjusted for daylight time if necessary: `s="2010-08-12 05:30:30.123"; date -d "$s $(date -d "$s" '+%z') + 0 months"`.